# angular 6 not rendering brighcove player when the video element is coming from api

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have an angular application and i have integrated the brightcove player in html

when i place the video tag in component.html

```
<video  width="100%" height="100%" data-account="2071817190001" data-player="Bk2rD1uW"
          data-embed="default" data-video-id="2700158695001" class="video-js" controls></video>
```

this code works fine and the video is loaded.

but when the same code comes from the api and i embedd the video tag in [innerHtml], Only the player shows and video is not loaded

Can someone tell the solution for it ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the code in ts file for that like this

```
import brightcovePlayerLoader from '@brightcove/player-loader';
```

then maybe after viewInit

```
brightcovePlayerLoader({
          refNode: '#player-container',
          accountId: '123',
          videoId: '123',
          refNodeInsert: 'replace',
          embedOptions: {
            tagName: brightcovePlayerLoader.EMBED_TAG_NAME_VIDEO
          }
        })
```

in your html

```
<div id="player-container"> </div>
```